# why can't I commit some files to CVS?

Tags: linux, cvs

I get a strange message when trying to commit to CVS.

For certain files I get

? dir/filename

after doing "cvs add dir" etc.

I am not sure what's the reason for that.

I am unable to add a new directory for the repository. Every time I do that, I get the ? before file names, and they are never committed (I know because this is a web server directory, and the files are not on the web).

On the other hand, the main directory works fine, and I can add and modify files there and commit them. Any idea?

Comment: needed an cvs add

Comment: ...as a side note, have you considered using git or hg instead?

Comment: it is not up to me...